# Setting variables conditionally while looping thru dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization

Having difficulty isolating data from other dataframes while vectorizing/looping through a dataframe.

`df`:

| NAME | CURRENT_BAL | AVAIL_BAL | TYPE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Abc | 1,000 | 2,000 | TypeA |
| Def | 1,000 | 2,000 | TypeB |

`settings`:

| Scenario | TypeA | TypeB |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Default | 1 | 2 |

`df` - desired output

| NAME | CURRENT_BAL | AVAIL_BAL | TYPE | 02/28/2023 | 03/31/2023 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Abc | 1,000 | 2,000 | TypeA | 2,000 | 0 |
| Def | 1,000 | 2,000 | TypeB | 1,000 | 1,000 |

The `settings` df tells the script how to spread out the Available Balance over the following periods. This is a reduced version of it and I'm looking to use specific month-end dates and longer periods with a variety of settings.

```
def build_table(df: pd.DataFrame, periods: int = 2, scenario: str = 'Default'):
    from datetime import date

    def create_entry(df: pd.DataFrame, i: int = 1, start_period: int = 1):
        number_periods = settings.loc[settings.Scenario == 'Default', df.Type]
        return (df.Avail_Bal / number_periods) if i <= number_periods else 0

    for i in range(periods):
        df[ (date.toady() + pd.offsets.MonthEnd() + pd.DateOffset(months=i)).date() ] = \
            create_entry(df, i, scenario)
    return df
```

As of now, running into errors with this line in trying to get a conditional value related to 1 row of the dataframe while its being vectorized:

`number_periods = settings.loc[settings.Scenario == 'Default', df.Type]`

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

There is a lot of work to be done on this project, but for now I'm trying to understand where I can use vectorization, and when I have to iterate through the rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want to use `.apply()` to apply the `create_entry` function to your dataframe.  In addition the result of your `.loc` method is a series, so you need to select the actual value (I am doing this with `.max()`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'NAME': ['Abc', 'Def'], 
    'CURRENT_BAL': [1000, 1000],
    'AVAIL_BAL': [2000, 2000], 
    'TYPE': ['TypeA', 'TypeB']
})
settings = pd.DataFrame({'Scenario': ['Default'], 'TypeA': [1], 'TypeB': [2]})


def create_entry(row, i):
    number_periods = settings.loc[settings.Scenario == 'Default', row.TYPE].max()
    return (row.AVAIL_BAL / number_periods) if i <= number_periods else 0

for i in range(1, 3):
    date_col = (date.today() + pd.offsets.MonthEnd() + pd.DateOffset(months=i)).date()
    df[date_col] = df.apply(lambda x: create_entry(x, i), axis=1)
```

output:

```
  NAME  CURRENT_BAL  AVAIL_BAL   TYPE  2023-03-28  2023-04-28
0  Abc         1000       2000  TypeA      2000.0         0.0
1  Def         1000       2000  TypeB      1000.0      1000.0
```